# I am trying to find out when a course will open at my school using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My school uses this web advisor.
https://webadvisor.uoguelph.ca/WebAdvisor/WebAdvisor?TOKENIDX=695853668&CONSTITUENCY=WBST&type=P&pid=ST-WESTS12A

You fill in the [Web advisor form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e54GV.png) and then you can see the [course information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcFYc.png)

I have tried a number of ways to solve this... Using beautiful soup, requests, Ixml...

I am still learning python and it seems this project is a little beyond my grasp at the moment

Here is a snippet of code that I tried using on the page after the form.

```
# scraper.py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://webadvisor.uoguelph.ca/WebAdvisor/WebAdvisor?
TOKENIDX=4624744027&SS=4&APP=ST&CONSTITUENCY=WBST'
#tutorial 'https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/hacked-my-universitys-
registration-system-python-twilio.html'
COURSE_NUM_NDX = 0
SEATS_NDX = 1

def get_open_seats():
    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    courses = {}

    for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        cols = [e.text for e in row.find_all('td')]
        if cols:
            courses[cols[COURSE_NUM_NDX]] = int(cols[SEATS_NDX])
    return courses
```

The issue though is that the URL after the form seems to expire? 
So the form must be filled out first?

Thank you so much for your time and knowlege. I would really love to get into that class! and in the process learn more about python!

Comment: If you only want to search using that form then it appears to be something you can do with http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Comment: I just got around to trying selenium against this site. The site 'actively refused' the connection. I can only suppose that the U of Guelph is fed up to the teeth with students. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate selenium, than you perform the login process and afterwards you can parse very easy the response take a look here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: I do want to search using the form, but then also find out when the course has a spot available.

Comment: @JustinFrancisco: Does 'spot available' mean that 'Status' is 'open'? Or that there's available capacity?

Comment: @billBell Spot available means that there is available capacity for an extra student to join
This would also change the status to open